# What is the difference between one hot encoding and 1-of-c encoding?

Tags: neural-network, encoding, one-hot-encoding

I am tasked with using 1-of-c encoding for a NN problem but I cannot find an explanation of what it is. Everything I have read sounds like it is the same as one hot encoding...
Thanks

Comment: do you mean [one-hot-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot)? This is different than [ordinal encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-hot-encoding-for-categorical-data/)

Comment: Sorry. Yes I meant one hot encoding. I changed the  question. Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know 1 of c is another name for one hot encoding

Comment: As I gather, the "c" is the number of new columns used to represent "c" number of categories. One-hot-encoding uses "c" columns, ergo 1-of-c (or as I've seen it in Zheng+Casari's FeatureEngineering book ,p78 - "1-of-k"). one-of-K-1 is "dummy" encoding, with full-zeros encoding as a category instead of as missing values.